# Require user to fill specific text in Edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a layout which has 3 radio buttons. with
Daily 1-30
Monthly 1-12
Hourly 1-23
Depending on these three values the user must enter text in Edit text field. User must enter these valid numbers only. Is there a way I can restrict the user to enter only valid numbers or what is the best way to acheive this

Comment: Seems like a use-case for `Regex`. But I'm not sure I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:inputType` to set keyboard to numbers only.

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/et_quantity"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="@string/quantity"
  android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
```

In addition you can put a simple use try catch block to check,

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.et_quantity);

int num = 0;

try{
 num = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
}
catch(Exception e){

  // Either display an AlertDialog or Toast to alert user that it was not a number.

}
```